# splitting strings by delimiter and other specific strings

Tags: java, string, split

I know how to split string by delimiters but I don't know how its done by a string. What I mean is I have a string such as

```
"(a AND b) OR c"
```

I want to split it so it ignores the brackets and the special words such as AND and OR. It should return me a string array of `{a, b, c}`

the same string could also be in the format such as `"(a & b) || c"`

I want to get the a,b,c into the string array and find their ID's and put their IDs into the initial string instead of them.

Comment: You might want to consider an EL or actual parser if the expressions can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: it won't be longer than 5 or 6 variables. Do you reckon its possible with simple java utilities ?

Comment: Is it just a limited list of symbols that need to be filtered out (in your example above, `{'(', ')', 'AND', 'OR', '&', '||'}`)? Sould you be able to enumerate such a list? (It's impossible to answer this question without more detail like that)

Comment: No just the limited list you just mentioned maybe "!" as well thats it

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? Do you know all possible "special words"?

Comment: {'(', ')', 'AND', 'OR', '&', "||", '!'} but if "||" creates and issue I don't mind having a single one "|"

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I have used split before, but not in this situation, I am getting the user input which is not long or any more complex as the above and will only have the list of symbols above and need to split them. but I don't know how split would work or any other utility ?

Comment: @Achilles - Are you saying that "|" is valid, but "||" is not? The answer I provide below assumes both should be removed (I assumed it was bitwise OR and regular OR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
String str = "(a AND b) OR c"; // Any string you want
String delims = "AND|OR|NOT|[!&|()]+"; // Regular expression syntax
String newstr = str.replaceAll(delims, " ");
String[] tokens = newstr.trim().split("[ ]+"); // RE syntax again
// tokens == ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Note that the delims is a regular expression and you can add to it if you have more delimeters. This one is going to replace "AND", "OR", "NOT", and one or more of the characters "!", "&", "|", "(", or ")". It replaces each of these occurances with a space, then splits the string on spaces (making sure to trim the front and back so we don't get those in our array).

Let me know if you have any questions on this. Hope it helps.

Comment: It works perfectly with the AND OR NOT and brackets but It doesn't quite always work with expressions containing the "!, &, |" for example "a ! b & c | d" wouldn't produce "abcd" It still does what I wanted. thought maybe I am missing something that u could explain. Cheers mate

Comment: @Achilles - Make sure you didn't introduce a syntax error when copying to your source, it is working for me ("a ! b & c | d" gives ["a", "b", "c", "d"]). If recopying doesn't fix it, I don't really know what the issue could be.

Comment: Just one last thing, I get get these tokens to to find their values from a DB I have and want to replace their int values instead of them back into the initial string. Do I have to search the string for the token and when found replace with the int value ? or is there a better way ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Do you mean that you need to take an input string like "(a AND b) OR c" and ultimately make it look like "(25 AND 12) OR 7"?

Comment: Yes, replacing the a, b, c with their values.